# While loggin in via fb to website, my function TestApi doesn't collect user data

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am trying to create login via facebook on the website. Unfortunately, while user is logged in and the function TestAPI() is triggered, I can't get the data from the user.

```
 function TestAPI(){ 
   FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function response (){
     if (response && !response.error){
       console.log(response); 
       buildProfile (response);
     }
   })
 } 

 function buildProfile(user){
   let profile = `
     <h3> $(user.name)</h3>
     <p> $(user.id) </h3>
     <p> $(user.email) </h3>`; 

   document.getElementById('profile').innerHTML = profile; 
 }
```

I've got following communicates in console:

```
sdk.js:108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of 
null 
at buildProfile (volunteer_system.html:65)
at response (volunteer_system.html:50)
at a.__wrapper.a.__wrapper (sdk.js:108)
at D (sdk.js:123)
at Object.b.onload (sdk.js:119)
at sdk.js:119
at sdk.js:50
at XMLHttpRequest.c.onreadystatechange (sdk.js:119)
```

Comment: for console.log (user) and console.log(reponse) I've got same answer, which is function indicated above....so it seems that somehow something is set unproperely...:         ƒ response (){
    if (response && !response.error){
    console.log(response);
    buildProfile (response); 
    } 
           }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the function instead of data

`console.log(response);`

This prints out the function instead of the response data, because `response` is the name of your function, not the name of the argument passed to the function. Consider the change below:

```
function TestAPI() { 
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response); 
            buildProfile (response);
        }
   });
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

This means that `document.getElementById('profile')` is returning null, it's possible that an element with this id does not exist in your DOM, but this is difficult to confirm without you sharing a code excerpt of the HTML you're trying to modify. You should have an element that looks something like this:

`<div id="profile"></div>`

Comment: obviously you're right. I missed this basic level mistake. Thank you very much :)